# Prune for each item in array in Json object with PlayJsonTransformer

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I've got a json structure looking like this:

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Tims",
      "surname": "YourAunty"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bobs",
      "surname": "YourUncle"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'd like to apply a transformer to make it look like this

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Tims"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bobs"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I've got so far is a transformer doing the removal of the surname, which works if it's not an array:

```
(__ \ 'persons \ 'surname).json.prune
```

How do I change this code to apply the prune to every single entry in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method, use case class to get out the required fields from json and then create a json as per your need.

```
val data = Json.parse("""{
                           "persons": [
                             {
                               "name": "Tims",
                               "surname": "YourAunty"
                             }, {
                               "name": "Bobs",
                               "surname": "YourUncle"
                             }
                           ]
                         }""")

case class Persons(name: String)
implicit val format = Json.format[Persons]

Json.toJson(Map("persons" -> (data \ "persons").asOpt[List[Persons]]))
```

**EDIT:**

It can be bit dirty but try this:

```
var jsonData: List[JsValue] = (data \ "persons").asOpt[List[JsValue]].fold(List.empty[JsValue])(identity) 

Json.toJson(Map("persons" -> jsonData.map(_.as[Map[String, String]]).map(_ - "surname")))// whatever you want to delete from map just type it here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm trying to do this without mapping to case classes. The reason for this is that the json structure that I'm working with is really large and it would be very verbose to map everything to case classes.

I've only got a couple of things that I want to remove, so it would make more sense to use a json transformer